# Handbrake CLI Transcoded Video not Playable in Quicktime and Itunes

Tags: itunes, quicktime, encoding, h.264

i am transcoding a bunch of videos with handbrake CLI. Therfore i use this presets:

```
    for i in `seq 0 10`; do f=$(($i-1)); HandBrakeCLI -i /Videofolder/ -t $i -O 
-f av_mp4 -e x264 -q 19 --h264-profile high --h264-level 4.1 
--x264-preset medium --decomb -q 19 -a 1,3 -s "1,3" 
-E copy:ac3 -o ~/Desktop/Video$(($f+1)).m4v; done
```

The Problem is  the result is not playable, not in Itunes neither in Quicktime. VLC does just fine. Quicktime starts trancoding this Video and after about 20 secs its playing it back. Has anyone got a hint for me whats my mistake?

Greenings and a big thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you set a flash drive as the destination for the finished video file? If the selected drive runs out of space while Handbrake is copying something, you’ll end up with an unreadable file.

Comment: No its a 1TB Fusion Drive with about 500gig left.